# I cant seem to find a newline matching character in scheme

Tags: scheme, newline

I'm attempting to find the new line character in a file and keep track of it with a counter so far i have

srcf is the source file

```
(if(equal? (peek-char srcf) (#\newline) )

  (begin

    (read-char srcf)
    (Lines srcf (+ Line 1))
  )

  (begin

    (read-char srcf)
    (Lines srcf Line)                       
  )
)
```

however i know that my equal? (peek)(#\newline) isn't working is there a character i can use for newline?

Answer (score 1):

The exact character depends on the newline character that is being used in the file, it could be `\n` (as is the norm for files in Unix / Mac) or `\r\n` (usually found in Windows). For starters, try comparing against `#\newline` and see if it works for you:

```
(equal? (peek-char srcf) #\newline)
```

... Notice that `#\newline` is *not* surrounded by parenthesis!